# Efficiently Create 1% Sample Using Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to process a large dataset (300GB) line by line using multiprocessing. I want to define a 1% random sample based one variable. My first step is to define the sample and then I want to read the data file using multiprocessing. I'm guessing that the script will run faster if the part where I define the set used for the random sample isn't run for each child. However, when I try to move that part of the script under the line `if __name__ == "__main__":` The child programs no longer seem to recognize random sample from the parent. I get the error:

> NameError: name 'id_pct1' is not defined

Where is the most efficient place to put the portion of the script where I define the random sample?

```
#define sample
uid = list(line.strip() for line in open('Subsets/unique_ids_final.txt'))
pct1 = round(len(uid)/100)
random.seed(1)
id_pct1 = set(random.sample(uid, k=pct1))
id_pct1.add(vname)

#read original file and write 1% sample using multiprocessing
def worker(chunkStart, chunkSize, q):
    with open('myfile.txt') as f:
        tlines = []
        f.seek(chunkStart)
        lines = f.read(chunkSize).splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            data = line.split('*')
            if data[30] in id_pct1: tlines.append(line)
        q.put(tlines)
        return tlines

def chunkify(fname,size=1024*1024):
    fileEnd = os.path.getsize(fname)
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        chunkEnd2 = 0
        while True:
            chunkStart = chunkEnd2
            f.seek(chunkStart)
            f.read(size)
            chunkEnd1 = f.tell()
            f.readline()
            chunkEnd2 = f.tell()
            chunkSz = 1024*1024 + chunkEnd2 - chunkEnd1 - 1
            yield chunkStart, chunkSz
            if chunkEnd2 >= fileEnd:
                break

def listener(q):
    with open('myfile1pct.txt', 'w') as out_f1:
        while True:
            m = q.get()
            if m == 'kill': break
            else:
                for line in m:
                    out_f1.write(line+'\n')
                    out_f1.flush()

def main():

    manager = mp.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()
    pool = mp.Pool()

    watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))

    jobs = []
    for chunkStart, chunkSize in chunkify('myfile.txt'):
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(worker,(chunkStart,chunkSize,q)))

    for job in jobs:
        job.get()

    q.put('kill')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you want those items in `#define` to be available throughout the entire program, you should use the keyword `global`[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/] in front of it. However, declaring global variables is really bad practice. You should consider just incorporating your `#define` logic in your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want those items in `#define` to be available throughout the entire program, you should use the keyword [`global`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword) in front of it. However, declaring global variables is generally considered bad practice. You should consider just incorporating your `#define` logic in your functions like so:

```
 #read original file and write 1% sample using multiprocessing
def worker(chunkStart, chunkSize, q):
    #define sample
    uid = list(line.strip() for line in open('Subsets/unique_ids_final.txt'))
    pct1 = round(len(uid)/100)
    random.seed(1)
    id_pct1 = set(random.sample(uid, k=pct1))
    id_pct1.add(vname)

    with open('myfile.txt') as f:
        tlines = []
        f.seek(chunkStart)
        lines = f.read(chunkSize).splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            data = line.split('*')
            if data[30] in id_pct1: tlines.append(line)
        q.put(tlines)
        return tlines

def chunkify(fname,size=1024*1024):
    fileEnd = os.path.getsize(fname)
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        chunkEnd2 = 0
        while True:
            chunkStart = chunkEnd2
            f.seek(chunkStart)
            f.read(size)
            chunkEnd1 = f.tell()
            f.readline()
            chunkEnd2 = f.tell()
            chunkSz = 1024*1024 + chunkEnd2 - chunkEnd1 - 1
            yield chunkStart, chunkSz
            if chunkEnd2 >= fileEnd:
                break

def listener(q):
    with open('myfile1pct.txt', 'w') as out_f1:
        while True:
            m = q.get()
            if m == 'kill': break
            else:
                for line in m:
                    out_f1.write(line+'\n')
                    out_f1.flush()

def main():

    manager = mp.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()
    pool = mp.Pool()

    watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))

    jobs = []
    for chunkStart, chunkSize in chunkify('myfile.txt'):
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(worker,(chunkStart,chunkSize,q)))

    for job in jobs:
        job.get()

    q.put('kill')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I've confirmed that this actually slows things down. I'm guessing that this is because the sample definition, (which takes a while to run), is rerun for every single chunk. That actually increases the number of times that the sample is defined, slowing things down. Is global the only solution?

Comment: You are right -- my solution probably does slow things down, but it fixes the problem you had in your question. If the solution answered your question, it should be marked as "Accepted" so others can benefit. If you are looking for an optimization of my answer, I suggest you head over to codereview[https://codereview.stackexchange.com/], they are experts at optimization over there :)

Comment: Fair enough. It does fix the error. If anyone else has ideas on how to do this more efficiently please let me know.

Comment: If you want a review of the code, really, post on codereview. That is the purpose of the site. If you review my account, I've posted there a few times and have gotten amazing feedback.

Comment: To speed things up, I tried to use the global solution, but I still got the same error. How would I implement that?

Comment: Which one of the files in your code is the 300GB one?

Comment: myfile.txt is 300GB. unique_ids_final.txt is 50MB so I don't want to make the random sample many times. I was looking around for other possible solutions and passing an object from parent to child as in https://thelaziestprogrammer.com/python/multiprocessing-pool-expect-initret-proposal seems like what I really want to do, but since I'm new to python I couldn't really understand the example.

Comment: That's because in my solution, I am reloading that 300GB file for every single worker created. Did you attempt to post on CodeReview[https://codereview.stackexchange.com/]?

Comment: I haven't. I'll give that a go.

Comment: (I want to avoid doing a code review here, since that isn't the purpose of _this_ site. But, I'll see you over there :))

Comment: If you have any suggestions, its on there at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234227/create-1-sample-using-multiprocessing-in-python

Comment: I will take a look this evening / tomorrow morning to edit @giacomo1488